# Laratrust seed is not working as expected

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication, admin

**Hello World**

I tried to use Laratrust for one of my projects and after I follow all the steps but I can't see any user in my databse.

I followed all the steps from [here](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/5.0/installation.html) and [here](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/5.0/configuration/after-installation.html) but I haven't found yet why there's no superadministrator or administrator in my database.

**The commands I used in order to install and go with Laratrust:**

```
composer require "santigarcor/laratrust:5.0.*"

php artisan vendor:publish --tag="laratrust"

php artisan laratrust:setup

composer dump-autoload

php artisan laratrust:migration

php artisan migrate

php artisan laratrust:seeder

composer dump-autoload
```

I also wrote `php artisan db:seed` but still nothing.

[image]

Thank you for your answers and sorry if my question is not really plausible.

Comment: so you added the call to their seeder class to your `DatabaseSeeder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` and add this in the `run()` method:

```
public function run()
{
    // ...

    $this->call(LaratrustSeeder::class);
}
```

Then, don't forget to modify the generate seeder creator `config/laratrust_seeder.php` to customize the seeder.

Answer (score 0):

edit config/laratrust_seeder.php.

- Change 'create_users' => false, to 'create_users' => true,

thank me later mate